Tengo problemas con el git, al hacer git add . Me salta un falta como si otro git se estuviera ejecutando
Fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/Ariel Reyna/OneDrive/Desktop/proyectoGrupo2/FrontProyectoFinalG2/.git/index.lock:file exists

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? GIT no puede crear archivo. fatal: Unable to create index.lock: File exists

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
